# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "inscription"

Tags: database, postgresql, reference, constraints, unique-constraint

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, I hope you'll be able to help me that would be really nice :)

I'm trying to create some tables but I got this error : ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "inscription"

Here is my query :

```
CREATE TABLE ue 
(
    id_ue varchar(30) primary key,
    designation varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ects int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE auditeur 
(
    id_auditeur int primary key,
    nom varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    prenom varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    date_nais varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tarif 
(
    id_tarif int primary key,
    tarif varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE inscription 
(
    annee int,
    id_auditeur int,
    id_tarif int,
    PRIMARY KEY (annee, id_auditeur),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_auditeur) REFERENCES auditeur (id_auditeur),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_tarif) REFERENCES tarif (id_tarif)
);

CREATE TABLE reglement 
(
    id_auditeur int,
    annee int,
    num_ordre int,
    montant int NOT NULL,
    primary key (id_auditeur, annee, num_ordre),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_auditeur) REFERENCES auditeur (id_auditeur),
    FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES inscription (annee)
);

CREATE TABLE inscrire 
(
    id_auditeur int,
    annee int,
    id_ue varchar(30),
    note1 int,
    note2 int,
    primary key (id_auditeur, annee, id_ue),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_auditeur) REFERENCES auditeur (id_auditeur),
    FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES inscription (annee),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_ue) REFERENCES ue (id_ue)
);
```

It should follow this logic model :

[Logic model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsnMt.png)

Here is also the relational schema of the database :

[Relational schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if2yE.png)

What I've tried : If I execute the query until the end of the creation of inscription it works, but the problem appears when I try to execute the last two creation because they refer to annee.

I can not add a unique constraint because it is for a homework and I have to insert a script with date (annee) and there are different dates (annee).If I do it, PostgreSQL tell me that there is a problem with the constraint unique. Normally if annee is a primary key it wouldn't be necessary to add a unique constraint right ?

I'm really lost.. thanks a lot to the people that will help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this:

`FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES inscription (annee)`

In the `inscription` table you have:

`PRIMARY KEY (annee, id_auditeur)`

That qualifies as a unique constraint, but your FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE is only trying to match half the `inscription` PRIMARY KEY. To make it work try:

**UPDATED**

`FOREIGN KEY (annee, id_auditer) REFERENCES inscription (annee, id_auditer)`

Then you can rid of:

`FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES inscription (annee)`

Comment: I changed it with what you've told me : 

CREATE TABLE reglement 
(
    id_auditeur int,
    annee int,
    num_ordre int,
    montant int NOT NULL,
    primary key (id_auditeur, annee, num_ordre),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_auditeur) REFERENCES auditeur (id_auditeur),
    FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES inscription (annee, id_auditeur)
);


It doesn't work, this time I get this error :

"ERROR:  number of referencing and referenced columns for foreign key disagree
SQL state: 42830"

Comment: My mistake, see UPDATED answer.

Comment: IT WORKED ! 

Thank you so much, I'm not sure my teacher will accept the answer because she really want us to do it a certain way, I'm pretty sure she will have her own way but for now it works !!

Thank you really much, it helped me a lot and above all thank to you I learn something new today, I won't do the same mistake in the future ! :)